# Testing Create method from controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am looking to test my `create` method in my controller, checking that my validations and flash messages set correctly. What I have so far is

```
it 'is invalid with invalid formatted email' do
  @message = Message.new(FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:message_invalid_email))
  @message.valid?
  expect(@message.errors[:email].first).to eq("Don't forget to add your email address")
end
```

But I have seen others setup their test like

```
@message = post :create, message: { params1: value1 }
```

What is the difference here and how should I be testing this?

And also when I try and test that a flash success has been set (using shoulda gem)

```
it 'is valid with correct parameters' do
  @message = Message.new(FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:valid_message))
  expect(@message).to be_valid
  expect(controller).to set_flash[:success]
end
```

I get this error

```
Expected the flash[:success] to be set, but no flash was set
```

This is my controller

```
def create
  @message = Message.new(message_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @message.valid?
      format.js { flash.now[:success] = "Thanks for your message, I'll be in touch soon" }
    else
      format.js { flash.now[:alert] }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The difference between your testing method and the other is that, in the first case, you are testing the **model**, and, in the second case, you are testing the **controller**. Also, validations should be tested on the model; flash messages and actions behaviour, within the controller.
2. I think that you are not calling your `create` action with `expect(controller).to set_flash[:success]`. Perhaps you should try something like the following block:

   ```
   it 'is valid with correct parameters' do
     post :create, message: { params1: value1 } # Whatever POST action
     expect(flash.now[:success].now).to be_present
   end
   ```
3. Is your controller working as expected? `format.js` is returning a string (`flash.now[:success]` or `flash.now[:alert]` instead of javascript code. Perhaps you should use `format.text`, or return nothing with `render status: :created, nothing: true`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have a `create.js.erb` file which sets the flash message in a div.. I keep getting 'ActionController::UnknownFormat:' when running your example

Comment: ok, got it now with a few tweaks, changed `expect(flash.now[:success].now).to be_present` to `expect(flash[:success]).to be_present` and also added `format: :js` with the post action

Comment: Why do you need the `js` format? Shouldn't be enought with plain or html text? Is it to allow `jsonp` ajax requests?